# ORA-00904: "NO_OF_PROJ_PER_CON_PY": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a fact table which will display the number of projects per consultant per year. It has 2 dimension tables 1 for time (report_time_dim) and the other for consultants(consultant_dim) then the main fact table (fact_table).

```
CREATE TABLE fact_table(
    fact_key INTEGER NOT NULL,
    consultant_key  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time_key    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_of_projects_py   INTEGER,
    no_of_consultants_py    INTEGER,
    no_of_accounts_py   INTEGER,
    no_of_proj_per_con_py   INTEGER,
    fk1_time_key    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_consultant_key  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "fact_table".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_fact_table PRIMARY KEY (consultant_key,time_key)
);

CREATE TABLE report_time_dim(
    time_key    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year    INTEGER,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "time_dim".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_report_time_dim PRIMARY KEY (time_key)
);

CREATE TABLE consultant_dim(
    consultant_key  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    project_id  INTEGER,
    consultant_id   INTEGER,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "consultant_dim".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_consultant_dim PRIMARY KEY (consultant_key)
);
```

Each table has it's own surrogate key and I have managed to populate the time and consultant tables successfully, however the issue I'm having is with the fact table. When I try to populate it I get the error ORA-00904: "NO_OF_PROJ_PER_CON_PY": invalid identifier. I am unsure how I can go about fixing this and populating the fact table so it will display the information I want. Any help would be appreciated.

```
--populate fact_table

--table that lists consultant ids, project ids and years
DROP TABLE temp_fact1;
CREATE TABLE temp_fact1 AS 
SELECT project_id, fk2_consultant_id, to_number(to_char(lds_project.pj_actual_start_date, 'YYYY')) as which_year FROM lds_project;

--display table
SELECT * FROM temp_fact1;

--list that counts the number of projects for each consultant and specify the year
DROP TABLE temp_fact2;
CREATE TABLE temp_fact2 AS
SELECT which_year, fk2_consultant_id, COUNT(*) project_id FROM temp_fact1 GROUP by fk2_consultant_id, which_year;

--display table
SELECT * FROM temp_fact2;

--fact table surrogate key
DROP SEQUENCE fact_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE fact_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 1000000
MINVALUE 1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

--load data

INSERT INTO fact_table (fact_key, consultant_key, time_key, no_of_proj_per_con_py) 
SELECT fact_seq.nextval, consultant_key, report_time_dim.time_key, no_of_proj_per_con_py FROM temp_fact2, report_time_dim WHERE temp_fact2.which_year = report_time_dim.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just running this select by itself - it's the last line in your script.

```
SELECT fact_seq.nextval, 
       consultant_key, 
       report_time_dim.time_key, 
       no_of_proj_per_con_py 
FROM temp_fact2, report_time_dim 
WHERE temp_fact2.which_year = report_time_dim.year;
```

It doesn't look like either TEMP_FACT2 or REPORT_TIME_DIM has a column named `no_of_proj_per_con_py`. I'm not sure where you want to pull that data from, actually.